# Visual studio settings css

Tags: css, visual-studio-2005, settings

My css file does not show any color high lights for the css what are the studio setting to enable it.Also my css intellisence won't work. I am using visual studio 2005. kindly help

Comment: can you make this more describe..

Comment: if i have say for example a css file opened in studio i get all the styles as plain  text without highlights i.e the font is always black for every class

Comment: you should check that are you using inline css in visual studio. check link of style file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the check box in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> Auto list member is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the file and select "open with..." and select "CSS Source Editor"